# How to solve SQL "Unknown column 'c' in 'field list'" in JAVA while there is actually no syntax problem with it

Tags: java, mysql, javafx

It supposed to be an INSERT statement to insert a row in one table in MySQL and then pop up with javafx UI, but there is always a syntax problem that some column is not in the field list.

I have tried to match the attributes one by one and checked  the MySQL table many times, but it still doesn't work.

1. Here is the java code to insrt data

```
//method to add a customer
    public static void insertCustomer(Customer customer)
    {
        try{
            //executeUpdate
            statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO customer(customer_id,age,first_name,last_name,phone_nr,passport_number)"
                    + " VALUES(2000,"
                    +customer.getAge()+","+customer.getFirst_name()+", "+  customer.getLast_name()+ ", " 
                     +  customer.getPhone_nr() 
                    + ", " +customer.getPassport_number() +");");
            System.out.println("客户数据插入语句完成，即将加入 ");
            customers.add(customer);
            System.out.println("customer_id下标+1这句话被窝去掉了！！！！！！！！！");
            //customer.setCustomer_id(customers.indexOf(customer) + 1);
        }

        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

2. Here is the exactly the same table supposed to be inserted into

```
customer_id | age |first_name| last_name | phone_nr| passort_umber
————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
____________|______|__________|___________|_________|_______________
.....
.....
.....
```

Error Message:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'c' in 'field list'
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdateInternal(StatementImpl.java:1355)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeLargeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:2128)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1264)
    at DataAccess.CustomerData.insertCustomer(CustomerData.java:56)
    at Application.Control.ViewCustomerSceneControl.handle_addB(ViewCustomerSceneControl.java:59)
    at Application.Control.ViewCustomerSceneControl.lambda$1(ViewCustomerSceneControl.java:39)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8411)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:394)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$358(GlassViewEventHandler.java:432)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:431)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$152(WinApplication.java:177)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I've been working on this for one day and still don't know hoe to solve this. I wish to know the solution.

Comment: 'c' in that error message is the `first_name` I wanted to insert.

Comment: You did not put the strings in quotes. Furthermore I strongly recommend using `PreparedStatement`+`setString`,`setInt`, ect. to make sure the literals are properly formatted in the query... BTW: Since we do not know about the inputs that result in the error, for questions like these it would be best to print the query to the console so that you can take a look at it/provide it to us...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should use prepared statements to avoid SQL injection.
Your problem is that you forgot the quotes in your string columns, so your sintax is wrong. This way it should work:

```
statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO customer(customer_id,age,first_name,last_name,phone_nr,passport_number)"
        + " VALUES(2000,"+customer.getAge()+",'"+customer.getFirst_name()+"', '"+  
        customer.getLast_name()+ "', '" +  customer.getPhone_nr() + 
        "', '" +customer.getPassport_number() +"');");
```